# Is my Asus 1000H netbook good enough for Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: ubuntu-netbook

I am looking to switch my Asus 1000H netbook (N270 1.6Ghz processor) from XP to Ubuntu. Is the latest version 12.10 the most suitable for this machine?

Comment: I should add, I also use Chrome/Chromium because Firefox runs poorly on the 1000H

Answer (score 4):

Welcome on Ask Ubuntu, Colin Lewis ! The requirements for Ubuntu Desktop are the following :

- 700 MHz processor (about Intel Celeron or better)
- 512 MiB RAM (system memory)
- 5 GB of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive but see LiveCD for an alternative approach)
- VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution
- Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media
- Internet access is helpful

So your processor frequency seems a little low (I think you have 667 Mhz max). If I were you I would consider to install [Xubuntu 12.10](http://xubuntu.org/) or [Lubuntu 12.10](http://lubuntu.net/). They would be more appropriate.

Xubuntu and Lubuntu are both very nice, but if you ever have the opportunity to try Ubuntu out, you will probably like its interface a lot !

Comment: The Atom N270 runs at 1.6 GHz, so you're fine in that area. In my experience with similar netbooks, you'll want to maximize your memory to the full 2GB, and run a distro that uses compiz but not unity. This might seem like a flame worthy response to run compiz, but the GMA950 gpu is well supported and offloading all the window dragging, etc away from the anemic processor actually helps. Just moving a window around rapidly without a compositing window manager can results in a high cpu load on an atom. With compiz, the load drops to almost nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu will run fine, I would also suggest adding Jupiter PPA to install Jupiter and jupiter-eeepc-support, the former increases battery life while the later enables super hybrid engine of asus netbooks.

Answer (score 2):

I have that exact model, I am using 12.10 on it right now. definitely faster than XP on the 1000H series. you will have to use a disk, or really dig into the bios because its a pain to make it boot to usb.

Comment: IIRC the U3 type of USB drives, which the system sees as a CD-ROM + a flash drive are a little easier to boot from on some systems that don't like booting from a USB HD. It's just more of a pain to copy the distro ISO to the U3 partition. The package 'u3-tool' has tools for doing this.